# Determine index an Object is in an array from the object itself

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way for objects inside an array to detect what slot they are in? If I had a Object array, could a Object inside the array detect what cell it is in without being explicitly told?

Comment: There's no magic here. You'd do this by iterating through the array in a for loop and checking.

Comment: AFAICT not a duplicate.  Surprising, upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately, how arrays work in Java is that the array simply "points" to an object. As a Java array only stores references (to objects), but any number of variables can reference the same object, so an Object has no idea where it lives in an array. In fact, the same object can be pointed to from several indices in the array!

Consider

```
Object o = new Object(); // The variable o has a "reference" to the Object in memory
Object[] arr = new Object[3]; // empty array to hold Object types
arr[0] = o; // the first index points to the Object we created above
arr[1] = o; // the second index points to that same object!
arr[2] = o; // still the same object! If we modified the original object (assuming it's not immutable) in any way, all the indices in this array would point to the modified object.
```

Hope this helps!

The fastest (easiest to write) way to iterate through an array of objects is

```
for (Object o : arr) {
    // do something to the local variable o, which you can think of as representing each object in your array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you need to do this, you probably have a design flaw.  Why does an `Object` need to know where it appears in the array?  If the index is of some semantic meaning or interest to the object, then the object should have an `int` field containing this information.  If you are trying to modify the original array based on one object then you probably have a poorly-factored class somewhere, e.g. if something such as this is happening:

```
class A {
    Object data[];
}

class B {
    remove(A a, Object instance) {
        // how to remove instance from a.data??
    }
}
```

Then really `B.remove` should be a method of `A` and hence have access to `data` in the first place.  And so forth.

Furthermore an array may just not be the right data structure.  If the index has much semantic value a `Map<Integer, Object>` may be more appropriate, although arrays are often used to represent this when the indices are continuous from `1..n` and the array is immutable.  In my silly example with `remove`, a `List` would be more appropriate.  Etc.

Comment: This is usually right, but there are exceptions. I work with structural engineering problems where list elements are intrinsic and must know their own index very quickly. In C or C++ this is straightforward. In java there are only extrinsic lists. As you imply, you're forced to store indices and keep them up to date with each list modification. This is awkward and error prone. In these problems I've never found a java implementation that is as clean as C/C++ allows.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    int i = Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(obj);
```

Comment: This is _very_ expensive and doesn't work right if there are duplicates under `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aaron_H said, no dice.  I'll add that you can work around it with something like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZenArray<IndexedString> z = new ZenArray(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
            z.set(i, new IndexedString("String " + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("I'm at index " + z.get(i).getIndex());
        }
    }
}

class ZenArray<T extends ZenArray.IndexedElement> {

    private Object [] a;

    interface IndexedElement {
        void setIndex(int i);
        int getIndex();
    }

    public ZenArray(int size) {
        a = new Object[size];
    }

    public void set(int i, T val) {
        val.setIndex(i);
        a[i] = val;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        return (T)a[i];
    }

    public int size() {
        return a.length;
    }
}

// An example of an indexed element implementation.
class IndexedString implements ZenArray.IndexedElement {

    int i;
    String val;

    public IndexedString(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public void setIndex(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex() {
        return i;
    }    
}
```